# Adding News to D2L through valence

Tags: desire2learn

I'm hoping I can get some help with adding news the D2L. I've tried a lot and have gotten to the point where I don't know what else to try.

The error I keep on getting is 404. So, I'm thinking that either something is wrong with the URL I'm trying, or the data I'm sending (or maybe content type that is being sent).

I saw that when adding news, you need to pass it a multipart/mixed POST body. So, I've tried changing my code to include that, but I'm still not sure what is going on.

I don't think it's a permissions thing because I'm supposed to have full access with this account (and it's not 403, but 404)

This is the data I'm trying to send.

Overall Content Type:

```
ContentType: multipart/mixed;boundary=6da451c7
```

Data Being Sent:

```
--6da451c7
Content-Type: application/json
{"Title":"Test News Title","Body":{"Text":"Testing Testing 123...Testing Testing","Html":"<p>Testing Testing 123...Testing Testing</p>"},"StartDate":"2013-11-17T20:07:11Z","EndDate":"2013-12-02T20:07:11Z","IsGlobal":false,"IsPublished":false,"ShowOnlyInCourseOfferings":false}
--6da451c7
```

And here is the URL i'm trying to POST data to (slightly modified to not include personal data).

```
https://gsutest.desire2learn.com/d2l/api/le/1.3/6606/news/?x_a={{TOKEN}}&x_b={{TOKEN}}&x_c={{TOKEN}}&x_d={{TOKEN}}&x_t={{TIMESTAMP}}
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, any help would be nice. I realize I could be creating my POST body data wrong, but I'm just not sure what to try.

Thanks!

----Edit----

Ran a POST using fiddler and captured this data

```
POST https://gsutest.desire2learn.com/d2l/api/le/1.3/6606/news?x_a={{APPID}}&x_b={{USERID}}&x_c=OR0KIlHnHChrBvhHT99HVkH4WrD9dw_uPlpTGzKOdXc&x_d=b_TmyIHdTOL3U5bkNa1UNn11S4Yg7Cc3GOBoI911gLE&x_t={{TIMESTAMP}} HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=1649e26b
Host: gsutest.desire2learn.com
Content-Length: 342
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

--1649e26b
Content-Type: application/json
{"Title":"Test News Title","Body":{"Text":"Testing Testing 123...Testing Testing","Html":"<p>Testing Testing 123...Testing Testing</p>"},"StartDate":"2013-11-19T21:07:03.838Z","EndDate":"2013-12-04T21:07:01.413Z","IsGlobal":false,"IsPublished":false,"ShowOnlyInCourseOfferings":false}
--1649e26b
```

----Edit #2----

Ran another POST using fiddler and captured this data. The data that I'm sending came from: http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/fileupload.html#simple-uploads (under the upload to news section)

```
POST https://gsutest.desire2learn.com:443/d2l/api/le/1.3/6606/news/?x_a={{APP_ID}}&x_b={{USER_ID}}&x_c=rdzAFVUE6xBS24N5nE_4Hf5sbwpvJH1OVJaK4Ow-XT8&x_d=TmadrEGw55aKwS1uuNo68kvaR_pvYLUWJdsFa7LhrEQ&x_t={{TIMESTAMP}}" HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;boundary=xxBOUNDARYxx
Host: gsutest.desire2learn.com:443
Content-Length: 270

--xxBOUNDARYxx
Content-Type: application/json
{"EndDate": null, "IsPublished": false, "ShowOnlyInCourseOfferings": false,"Title": "Test title", "Body": {"Text": "Test body text", "HTML": null},"StartDate": "2013-02-20T13:15:30.067Z", "IsGlobal": false}
--xxBOUNDARYxx
```

I'm still getting "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found" as the response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you provided, I discovered that you are missing the millisecond value in your UTCDateTime format. By adding a millisecond value of .067 and .068 to each of the dates, I am able to POST successfully. I did this by using the [Getting Started Sample](http://samples.valence.desire2learn.com/) against an LMS where I have an Instructor account with privileges to POST News items.

Comment: still getting 404. If I didn't create my token correctly, it would say invalid token not 404 right?

Comment: That's correct - the invalid token error is explicit. Have you tried doing a network trace using something like Fiddler to get more details on the cause of the 404 error?

Comment: watched with fiddler, updated my main post with the dump I was able to get from there. If you can see my email, it's current. I'll be more then happy to send along the actual url and stuff I'm using, let me know.

Comment: Your fiddler trace implies that you are POSTing to this API path: `/d2l/api/le/1.3/6606/news`. This is not a valid API path: it must have a trailing slash for this call. You did have a trailing slash in your original example, but a badly formatted date/time stamp. Perhaps this trailing slash is now the issue?

Comment: hum...I'm still not doing something right. I've gone back and added the trailing slash back in (don't remember when I removed it). Other then the missing slash, everything else appears to be right?

Comment: I am able to use the route and successfully post the data included in Edit #2 using the Getting Started Sample referenced above, and modifying the orgid to a valid org in my LMS. Are you certain that 6606 corresponds to an existing org?

Comment: Have you also tried using the Getting Started Sample against your environment to post to this route with this data? Running a fiddler trace while doing that may be a good basis to compare what your code is sending vs. what the Getting Started Sample sends.

Comment: One more thought - what version of the LMS are you running? Just want to be sure you're calling the correct version of the API -- If you do a GetVersions call using the Getting Started Sample you can be sure if your LMS supports the version 1.3 of the LE APIs.

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I have a bad org unit code. What is a good way to find the org unit code for the main site? I thought it was 6606, but I logged into the sample getting started site, ran the code and it also returned 6606 so I'm worried that I have the wrong code.

Comment: The Org Info call will return the base org unit: http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-organization-info